# Node not connecting to static/trusted peers etherum geth [ public network ]

Tags: go-ethereum, peers, mainnet, node-discovery, devp2p

I followed all the steps of adding trusted and static peers:

1. Manually adding the peers to configuration file `config.toml`
2. Using `addTrustedPeers` and `addPeers` of the geth console
3. set the `--nodiscover` flag

The `net.PeerCount` returns 0 everytime I try to see if the node is connected to any of the added peers.

I also checked the security groups and firewall just to make sure nothing is being blocked.

Any idea how to fix that issue?

Note the command to start geth client is as follows:
`sudo geth --mainnet --syncmode full --datadir /data/ethereum  --http --http.addr=0.0.0.0 --http.port=8545 --http.vhosts=* --http.api=admin,personal,eth,net,web3,txpool --authrpc.vhosts=* --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0 --authrpc.port=8551 --authrpc.jwtsecret=/home/ubuntu/.setup/secret/jwtsecret --nodiscover --config /data/ethereum/config.toml`

Comment: It the node behind a proxy, nat network or firewall?

Comment: No, it is not @Ismael